# How to integrate 3rd party Cordova plug-in with IBM MobileFirst-based hybrid apps

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Please assist us by sharing your experience to integrate 3rd party Cordova plug-in within IBM MobileFirst-based Hybrid App. So far we tried 3 integration options as follows.

IBM MFP version : v 7.1.x
Cordova Plug-in version : 6.3.1

1. Via Eclipse (added 3rd party provided Cordova plug-ins within Eclipse based IBM Worklight Studio).

   Issue - Resources embedded into AAR files are not reachable from JAR files. Through JAR, tried to invoke class file of Camera activity, which is throwing exception showing R$layout doesn't exist.

   [image: CameraActivity]
2. Via IBM Cordova app (MobileFirst CLI): Issue - Same as option 1 above
3. Via command line as standard Cordova: No issue, as a standalone Cordova project the plug-in is working fine.

The Cordova plug-in(s) are used to integrate Hybrid mobile application which is developed using IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1, with IBM Datacap's OCR (optical character recognition).

Comment: What is DataCap? Does it have a JavaScript SDK? a native SDK? Is it meant to work in Cordova-based apps?

Comment: @IdanAdar, The IBM Datacap is ECM product of IBM. The OCR functionality of Datacap is bundled as Native SDK (Android Datacap SDK, iOS Datacap SDK). OCR use case comes as part of registration process of main Hybrid mobile application, which is build on IBM MFP. Hence , need to integrate Cordova Plug-ins to interact with OCR features of Native SDK. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: We have followed the steps given below, which resulted successful build. Hope these steps are useful for similar integration scenario. As IBM MFP CLI uses ANT to build, which was not referencing .aar of 3rd party plugins, we have used Android studio and imported Android environment, which supports gradle.                                               Step1- Converted hybrid mobile app into MFP Cordova project by following steps given in the link-
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_creating_cordova_app_cli.html

Comment: Step2- Included the 3rd party Cordova plug-ins inside MFP Cordova project
Step3- Imported the native android code which is generated from IBM MFP CLI into Android Studio
Step4- In Android Studio, Added dependencies of 3rd party plug-in gradle reference in MFP Cordova project's build.gradle
Step5- In Android Studio,  Added supporting JAR files (app compact V7 JAR) into MFP Cordova plug-in project
Step6- In Android Studio, Built MFP Cordova project with gradle

Comment: Step3- Imported the native android code which is generated from IBM MFP CLI into Android Studio
Step4- In Android Studio, Added dependencies of 3rd party plug-in gradle reference in MFP Cordova project's build.gradle
Step5- In Android Studio,  Added supporting JAR files (app compact V7 JAR) into MFP Cordova plug-in project
Step6- In Android Studio, Built MFP Cordova project with gradle

Comment: Why write this as a comment? Please change this to an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The IBM Datacap is ECM product of IBM. The OCR functionality of Datacap is bundled as Native SDK (Android Datacap SDK, iOS Datacap SDK). OCR use case comes as part of registration process of main Hybrid mobile application, which is build on IBM MFP. Hence,need to integrate Cordova Plug-ins to interact with OCR features of Native SDK. Hope this clarifies.
We have followed the steps given below, which resulted in successful build. Hope these steps are useful for similar integration scenario. As IBM MFP CLI uses ANT to build, which was not referencing .aar of 3rd party plugins, we have used Android studio and imported Android environment, which supports gradle. 
Step1- Converted hybrid mobile app into MFP Cordova project by following steps given in the link- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_creating_cordova_app_cli.html
Step2- Included the 3rd party Cordova plug-ins inside MFP Cordova project 
Step3- Imported the native android code which is generated from IBM MFP CLI into Android Studio
Step4- In Android Studio, Added dependencies of 3rd party plug-in gradle reference in MFP Cordova project's build.gradle 
Step5- In Android Studio, Added supporting JAR files (app compact V7 JAR) into MFP Cordova plug-in project 
Step6- In Android Studio, Built MFP Cordova project with gradle.